# How to programmatically create nested layer groups?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Using PyQGIS via the QGIS 2.4.0 Python console and the editor, I can create parallel groups for storing some layers with:

```
MyFirstGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 1')
MySecondGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 2')
```

The variables `MyFirstGroup` and `MySecondGroup` will store the GroupIDs (apparently 1 & 2).
But how can I create the groups in a nested way so that `MySecondGroup` is a sub-group of `MyFirstGroup`?

Looking at the API docs, I find the [addGroup](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#a25a8cf67b140383bab0c75e90a3eb3f8) function twice - one time expecting the parent group with a `QTreeWidgetItem` and one time via a `int parentIndex`.

When using the latter form as

```
MySecondGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 2', parentIndex = 1)
```

then I get a `TypeError: QgsLegendInterface.addGroup(QString, bool expand=True, QTreeWidgetItem parent=None): 'parentIndex' is not a valid keyword argument`

When only using

```
MySecondGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 2', 1)
```

or

```
MySecondGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 2', MyFirstGroup)
```

then groups are not created nested but in parallel.

What is the correct way to achieve this or where do I get the corresponding `QTreeWidgetItem` object for `MyFirstGroup` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legend interface has been refactored since 2.4 version.
A detailed description how to add nodes, groups and subgroups can be found here:

http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/

and here

http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/

regards

Answer (score 4):

You may use the *addGroup* function like this:

```
MyFirstGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 1')
MySecondGroup = iface.legendInterface().addGroup('Group No. 2', true, MyFirstGroup)
```